# Confusing system information issue

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, system-info

I'm using a little piece of Python code to see the system info. When I try this on my system, I got these;

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'AMD64'
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
>>>
```

AMD64 means my system is 64-bit, how ever; when I go to `C`, there is `(x86)` next to `Program Files`. Since `x86` means 32-bit, why does `x86` is there if my system is 64-bit?

Comment: Also [What is the difference between “Program Files” and “Program Files X86”?](http://superuser.com/questions/299543/what-is-the-difference-between-program-files-and-program-files-x86)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder called `Program Files (x86)` exists only on x64 systems. It is used to install non-x64 programs (which can still run on a x64 system). The actual x64 programs are stored in the `Program Files` folder, but the name is always translated in your language (if I go to C: I will see it as `Programmes` because my Windows is in French).

If you press the key combination **Windows** + **Pause/Attn** or go to Control Pannel --> System there will be "(32 bits)" next to the name of the OS if your Windows is 32 bits, and there will be nothing if it is 64 bits.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if there is no mere problem ^^